# mqtt receiver not getting data

Tags: mqtt, node-red

I'm a beginner in `MQTT`, I think I have misunderstand the concept. I have published a message (ex:m1001) using node red with QOS 1 & 2, the broker received the message. At that time either the subscriber or the receiver is disconnected  due to power or internet failure.

When I now reconnect to the broker, I'm not getting the message (ex:m1001) in the subscriber and if I set `retain=true`, the message gets stored in the broker and it executes the message repeatedly until I clear it manually.

I require the each message is delivered from pub to sub without a failure. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What you describe is the expected behavoiur of `MQTT`. Despite publishing messages to subchannels and deleting the `retain` flag afterwards, there is nothing elese I have seen in a working example yet.

Answer (score 1):

QOS applies to both subscribers and publishers and is only between the one client and the broker. This means that if a client publishes a message a QOS 1/2 then the QOS handshake is only between the publisher and the broker. The subscribing clients also need to request QOS 1/2 to get assured delivery

To get messages delivered to the subscribers when they reconnect they need to have subscribed to the topic at QOS 1/2 and make sure the cleanSession flag is set to false when they reconnect.

Retained messages are different and the last retained message will always be delivered to a client when it subscribes to a matching topic until the retained message is cleared (by publishing a null payload with the retained bit set).